# Compare within- and between-individuals variances with lme4?

Tags: mixed-model, random-effects-model, intraclass-correlation

How can I compare the variances of two random effects variables?

I have an experiment with several proteins measured in individuals (ind = 4 levels) before and after a treatment (treatment = 2 levels factor), which was replicated one week after (day, 2 levels).

The main goal of the replication was to measure how individual responses varied between the days, i.e., if they were similar (irrespective of treatment).

I'm looking for a way to compare the **variance between-subjects and within-subjects (across two days)** to rank the compounds (I'm interested in higher between-ind. variance with least within-subj. variance across days).

I tried some mixed models (lme4), here are two of them:
The dataset is here for reproducibility: https://pastebin.com/H5VcJhcx

**1. Random intercepts for individuals and day:**

```r
lmm1 <- lmer(value~treatment+(1|day) + (1|ind), data = dat_long, 
                     subset = protein == "PROT1")

summary(lmm1)

REML criterion at convergence: -119

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-2.0703 -0.6838  0.0944  0.6249  1.7122 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ind      (Intercept) 0.001942 0.0441  
 day      (Intercept) 0.000754 0.0275  
 Residual             0.005464 0.0739  
Number of obs: 62, groups:  ind, 26; day, 2

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error      df t value
(Intercept)         3.1094     0.0260  1.2199   119.6
treatmentinfected   0.2952     0.0189 29.4899    15.6
                  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          0.002 ** 
treatmentinfected  8.6e-16 ***
```

**2. Random intercepts for day + random intercepts and slopes for individuals:**

```r
lmm2 <- lmer(value~treatment+(1|day) + (treatment|ind), data = dat_long, 
             subset = protein == "PROT1")

summary(lmm2)

REML criterion at convergence: -120

Scaled residuals: 
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-2.026 -0.758  0.080  0.568  1.931 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name              Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 ind      (Intercept)       0.001038 0.0322       
          treatmentinfected 0.000923 0.0304   1.00
 day      (Intercept)       0.000948 0.0308       
 Residual                   0.005027 0.0709       
Number of obs: 62, groups:  ind, 26; day, 2

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error      df t value
(Intercept)         3.1108     0.0268  1.1242   116.0
treatmentinfected   0.2968     0.0192 26.3392    15.5
                  Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)         0.0031 ** 
treatmentinfected  9.8e-15 ***
---
```

The complete dataset has more individuals, but without the second day replication. I tried both a smaller with only the balanced set (4 individuals) or with all (26 ind). I believe that for mixed effects the larger unbalanced are better, right?

For some proteins, the model is singular (zero or almost zero variance for ind or for day).

**Would this answer my question? Can I use the ratio of variances/SD (ind/day) to select proteins with higher variation between individuals compared to across-days within the same individual?**

Are there more elegant/correct ways to do this?

I appreciate if you have recommendations of books for learning this subject further. I'm using Gelman & Hill 2007.

Thank you.

Comment: It makes no sense to fit random intercepts for `day` since there are only 2 days. You are asking the software to estimate a variance for a normally distributed variable from only 2 observations. You can't hope to get a sensible estimate for this so any comparisons using it are equally hopeless.

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I thought so as well, but my advisor insisted because someone did in a paper... Do you think it is reasonable to model `day` as fixed and rank the proteins by the estimate?

Comment: You're welcome, but that's not clear. Why don't you include the whole dataset and include all the proteins all in the same model ?

Comment: Haven't thought about that. Like this? lmer(value~treatment*protein+day+(1+treatment|ind)

Comment: Yes !  When you split the data, you lose a lot of statistical power.